# Unable to delete / move MS Access file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm hoping this is a simple fix...

I can't move / delete my MS Access database. It is not open but it is connected to my VBA tool which is connected to the database (not sure does this make a difference).

This is how it looks in file explorer.

[image: Try Again Error Message]

Comment: The laccdb should automatically delete when accdb closes but sometimes fails without known cause. What do you mean by 'VBA tool'? What is causing the locking file to persist?

Comment: *simple fix* -- reboot.

Comment: try thinking windows and not access.  Here is one link to a guide for deleting uncooperative files: https://www.wikihow.com/Delete-a-File-or-Folder-Showing-Error-%22Access-Is-Denied%22#:~:text=Locate%20the%20file%20stored%20on%20your%20hard%20drive.&text=Click%20the%20%22Start%20menu%22%20and,are%20at%20your%20Start%20screen.&text=Right%2Dclick%20on%20the%20file%20and%20choose%20%22Properties.%22,of%20the%20file%20or%20folder.

Comment: Thanks guys. I logged off last night and was able to delete it this morning. Can't put my finger on why that happened - task manager didn't show that it was running...